# FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process - Additionally FirebaseApp.initializeApp() doesn't work. Dependency Problem?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services

I added the following line into the project gradle file:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

This into the module gradle file:

```
dependencies {

    ...    

    // GPS
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

    // FireBase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And Added this into AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".pushclient.PushService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I downloaded the `google-services.json` from FireBase Console and placed it at the correct position

But I get the following error when trying to use Firebase:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process
```

When I initialize it manuall and try to get the ID, I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance() must not be null
```

I tried to set up a fresh new App and it works, but actually not with my project.
I think there is a dependency problem, but there is no error or hint.

I tried many different versions, none seems to work.

Do you have a solution for that?

Comment: Did you check google-services.json? Maybe it contains wrong project id?

Comment: have you put the configurations in you AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: It's correct. I downloaded it from the firebase console @Dmitriy Kholin

Comment: I will add the Manifest to my post @Paras

Comment: Also, can you try "fresh new App" with all dependencies from your main project? So it will be possible to eliminate the problem in dependencies.

Comment: I will try that, thanks @Dmitriy Kholin

Comment: It works with all the dependencies in a new fresh app @Zeon

Comment: Where you call "FirebaseApp.initializeApp(appContext)"? Perhaps you are trying to use FireBase before this call?

Comment: I tried to initalize it in onCreate in my MainActivity. But normally Firebase should be initialized automatically...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was `tools:node="replace"` in an AndroidManifest.xml of a sub-module..
After I removed it and fixed the Manifest-Merger issues it worked fine!

Google should really give us a small hint that Firebase won't start if you use `tools:node="replace"` anywhere in your project.

Answer (score 0):

You must add configuration JSON to your app folder.
You can download this file on page with your project on firebase site.

Open Firibase Site -> Select you project -> Setting -> Select your app -> Clcik "google-services.json"

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I forgot that. The google-services.json is at the correct position

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error for initialising a firebase instance, you can use below method before you are trying to get the instance.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

Assuming you have added:-

- google-services.json
- done configuration in AndroidManifest.xml

You need to add `google-services` dependency in your project level gradle file.

```
buildscript {
   repositories {---}
   dependencies {
       ---
       ---
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
   }
}
```

You need to remove `gcm` dependency as well.

<strike>implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'</strike>

Comment: If I do this, it's still not initialized correctly. You can see the error in my post

Comment: can you post your root level gradle file wanted to check the config.

Comment: can you remove `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.4'` dependency and check.